# value for session data question number not getting incremented and passed in codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please advice me as value for session data question_number not getting incremented and passed in Codeigniter project
The old value question_number  of 1 is always passed as the question number
the code is supposed to set question_number as 1 initially and then when the user submits the form the first time, and the form data is processed by the same document, the question number is supposed to be incremented by one and passed to the same form below
but unfortunately, this new question number is not passed to the hidden input type
see the code below

$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbName);

```
                                                if (!$this->session->userdata("user_id")) {
                                                    header("location:" . base_url() . "login");
                                                }
                                                $_SESSION['error'] = '';
                                                $_SESSION['success'] = '';

                                                // template methods start here ==========================================

                                                if (isset($_POST["LaunchTest"])) {

                                                        $test_id = addslashes($_POST['id']);
                                                        echo("test_id: " . $test_id . "<br />");
                                                        $session_id = addslashes($_POST['session_id']);
                                                        echo("session_id: " . $session_id . "<br />");
                                                        $counter = addslashes($_POST['counter']);
                                                        echo("counter: " . $counter . "<br />");
                                                        $score = addslashes($_POST['score']);
                                                        echo("score: " . $score . "<br />");
                                                        $question_number = addslashes($_POST['question_number']);
                                                        echo("question_number: " . $question_number . "<br />");
                                                        $answer = addslashes($_POST['hidden_answer']);
                                                        echo("answer: " . $answer . "<br />");
                                                        $user_choice = addslashes($_POST['radio_choice']);
                                                        echo("user_choice: " . $user_choice . "<br />");
                                                        $start_id = addslashes($_POST['start_id']);
                                                        echo("start_id: " . $start_id . "<br />");
                                                        $end_id = addslashes($_POST['end_id']);
                                                        echo("end_id: " . $end_id . "<br />");
                                                        $current_question= $question_number;
                                                        if ($user_choice==$answer) {
                                                            $score++;
                                                        }
                                                        $preventRepeat = [];
                                                        $question_number = $question_number+1;
                                                        echo("new Question number: " . $question_number . "<br />");
                                                        $new_question = $question_number;
                                                        $_SESSION['question_number'] = $question_number;

                                                        $organisation = $_SESSION['organisation'];
                                                        date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');
                                                        $today = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

                                                        $sql_query = "UPDATE cbt_attempts_tbl SET "
                                                        . "currentQuestion ='"
                                                        . $current_question . "',"
                                                        . "score ='"
                                                        . $score . "',"
                                                        . "created_date ='"
                                                        . $today . "'"
                                                        . " WHERE session_id = '"
                                                        . $session_id .
                                                        "'";
                                                        ;   //$displayedRowCount = $rowCount;
                                                        echo $sql_query . "<br />";
                                                        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql_query) or die("No data returned from DB Query");
                                                        //$candidate_quest_count++;
                                                        echo "database updated succesfully. <br />";

                                                        $current_question++;


                                                        if ($question_number > $_SESSION['total_questions']) {
                                                            //calculate score
                                                            $score_output = calculateScore($score, $_SESSION['total_questions']);
                                                            //end test
                                                            header("location:" . base_url() . "score?id=" . $test_id .
                                                        "&test_session=" . $session_id. "score=". $score_output);
                                                        } else {
                                                            //            myRandomNum = generateSecondRandomNumber();
                                                            $myRandomNum = generateRandomNumber($start_id, $end_id);
                                                            echo("myRandomNum: " . $myRandomNum . "<br />");

                                                            //$myRandomNum = preventRepeatingQuestions($myRandomNum);
                                                            $quesionAtRand_str = getQuestionAtRandom($myRandomNum, $con);

                                                             $QuestData_arr = explode("~", $quesionAtRand_str);
                                                            //echo("QuestData_arr is: " . $QuestData_arr . "<br />");

                                                            $Question = $QuestData_arr[1];
                                                            //echo("Question is: " . $Question . "<br />");

                                                            $OptA = $QuestData_arr[2];
                                                            //echo("OptA is: " . $OptA . "<br />");

                                                            $OptB = $QuestData_arr[3];
                                                            //echo("OptB is: " . $OptB . "<br />");

                                                            $OptC = $QuestData_arr[4];
                                                            //echo("OptC is: " . $OptC . "<br />");

                                                            $OptD = $QuestData_arr[5];
                                                            //echo("OptD is: " . $OptD . "<br />");

                                                            $Answer = $QuestData_arr[6];
                                                            //echo("Answer is: " . $Answer . "<br />");
                                                        }

                                                }

                                                ?>


                                                <?php include('admin_block.php'); ?>
                                                <br/>

                                                <?php
                                                if (!isset($_GET["id"])) {
                                                    $_SESSION['error'] = '<label class="text-danger">nothing selected.</label><br />';
                                                    header("location:" . base_url() . "launchtest");
                                                    exit();
                                                }
                                                $test_id = addslashes($_GET['id']);
                                                //display deleted succesfully
                                                //header return to update screen
                                                $organisation = $_SESSION['organisation'];
                                                $user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
                                                // main start
                                                //-----FIRST TIME RUN STARTS HERE---

                                                if (!isset($test_session_id)) {
                                                            $arr_usr_choice = [];
                                                            $arr_correct_answer = [];
                                                            $arr_usr_choice[0] = "nothing";
                                                            $arr_correct_answer[0] = "nothing";
                                                            $candidate_quest_count = 1;
                                                            $question_number = 1;
                                                            $preventRepeat = [];
                                                            $counter = 1;
                                                            $current_question = 1;
                                                            $score = 0;
                                                            $_SESSION["score"] = 0;
                                                            $test_session_id = generateTestSessionId();
                                                            //echo("test_session_id is: " . $test_session_id . "<br />");

                                                            //gettestdetails from summary table
                                                            $testDetails = getTestDetailsFromSummary($con, $test_id);
                                                            //echo("testDetails: " . $testDetails . "<br />");

                                                            $dataFromSmryTble_arr = explode("~", $testDetails);
                                                            $test_name= $dataFromSmryTble_arr[2];
                                                            //echo("test_name: " . $test_name . "<br />");

                                                            $type = $dataFromSmryTble_arr[6];
                                                            //echo("type: " . $type . "<br />");

                                                            $subject = $dataFromSmryTble_arr[5];
                                                            //echo("subject: " . $subject . "<br />");

                                                            $total_questions = $dataFromSmryTble_arr[3];
                                                            //echo("total_questions: " . $total_questions . "<br />");

                                                            $start_id = $dataFromSmryTble_arr[0];
                                                            //echo("start_id: " . $start_id . "<br />");

                                                            $end_id = $dataFromSmryTble_arr[1];
                                                            //echo("end_id: " . $end_id . "<br />");
                                                            $_SESSION['total_questions'] = $total_questions;
                                                            loadDetailsToAttemptsTbl(
                                                                $con,
                                                                $test_id,
                                                                $test_session_id,
                                                                $test_name,
                                                                $type,
                                                                $subject,
                                                                $total_questions,
                                                                $start_id,
                                                                $end_id
                                                            );


                                                        //1. get test takers first name and lastname

                                                        if (!isset($_SESSION['firstname']) || !isset($_SESSION['lastname'])) {
                                                            header("location:" . base_url() . "enter_student_details?id=" . $test_id .
                                                                "&test_session=" . $test_session_id);
                                                        }
                                                        $firstname = $_SESSION['firstname'];
                                                        $lastname = $_SESSION['lastname'];

                                                        $output = displayFirstQuestion($con, $test_session_id); // duisplays one Question
                                                            //echo("output is: " . $output . "<br />");

                                                            $QuestData_arr = explode("~", $output);
                                                            //echo("output is: " . $output . "<br />");

                                                            $Question = $QuestData_arr[1];
                                                            //echo("Question is: " . $Question . "<br />");

                                                            $OptA = $QuestData_arr[2];
                                                            //echo("OptA is: " . $OptA . "<br />");

                                                            $OptB = $QuestData_arr[3];
                                                            //echo("OptB is: " . $OptB . "<br />");

                                                            $OptC = $QuestData_arr[4];
                                                            //echo("OptC is: " . $OptC . "<br />");

                                                            $OptD = $QuestData_arr[5];
                                                            //echo("OptD is: " . $OptD . "<br />");

                                                            $Answer = $QuestData_arr[6];
                                                            //echo("Answer is: " . $Answer . "<br />");
                                                            $_SESSION['question_number'] = $question_number;

                                                }
                                                //-----FIRST TIME RUN ENDS HERE---
                                                echo '<form method="post" action="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?id=' . $test_id .
                                                        '&test_session=' . $test_session_id .'"';
                                                echo '<h2 class="section-heading animated">'. $test_name .'</h2>';


                                                echo '<TABLE class="my_style" border="0"><TR><TD>' . $firstname . " ". $lastname . '</TD></TR></TABLE>';


                                                echo '<font color="#fff"><table class="my_style" border="0" cellpadding="2">';
                                                echo '<tr >';
                                                echo '<td valign="top" >' . $_SESSION["question_number"]  . '</td>';
                                                echo '<td valign="top" colspan="3" scope="col"><b>' . $Question . '</b></td>';
                                                echo '</tr >';
                                                echo '<tr >';
                                                echo '<td></td><TD WIDTH="2%">A.</TD><td WIDTH="2%"><input name="radio_choice" type="radio" value="A" required /></td><td valign="top" >' . $OptA . '</td>';
                                                 echo '</tr >';
                                                 echo '<tr >';
                                                 echo '<td></td><TD WIDTH="2%">B.</TD><td WIDTH="2%"><input name="radio_choice" type="radio" value="B" /></td><td valign="top" >' . $OptB . '</td>';
                                                 echo '</tr >';
                                                 echo '<tr >';
                                                 echo '<td></td><TD WIDTH="2%">C.</TD><td WIDTH="2%"><input name="radio_choice" type="radio" value="C" /><td valign="top"  >' . $OptC . '</td>';
                                                 echo '</tr >';
                                                 echo '<tr >';
                                                 echo '<td></td><TD WIDTH="2%">D.</TD><td WIDTH="2%"><input name="radio_choice" type="radio" value="D" /><td valign="top" >' . $OptD. '</td>  <input type="hidden"  value="'.$Answer.'" name="hidden_answer" /> ';
                                                echo '</tr>';
                                                 echo '</tr >';
                                                echo '<td colspan="4" ><input type="submit" style="background-color: #008CBA;" value="Next Question" name ="LaunchTest" onClick="checkRadios()"/>';
                                                  echo '<input  type="hidden" name="id" value="'. $test_id.'"/>';
                                                echo '<input  type="hidden" name="question_number" value="'. $_SESSION["question_number"] .'"/>';
                                                echo '<input  type="hidden" name="session_id" value="'.$test_session_id.'"/>';
                                                echo '<input  type="hidden" name="counter" value="'.$counter.'"/>';
                                                echo '<input  type="hidden" name="score" value="'.$_SESSION["score"] .'"/>';
                                                echo '<input  type="hidden" name="start_id" value="'.$start_id.'"/>';
                                                echo '<input  type="hidden" name="end_id" value="'.$end_id.'"/>';
                                                echo '</td>';
                                                echo '</tr >';

                                                echo '</table></font>';
                                                echo '</form>';
                                                // main end
                                                ?>
```

Comment: 1.) this doesn't look like codeigniter - its just code written in PHP; 2.) your formatting is a bit "messy" and your question is pretty unclear imho - pls clarify the problem.

Comment: Please separate the view and controller code. That is the whole idea behind using a framework.

Comment: From just a cursory look, I might have missed something: What is `$test_session_id` in your code? If it's not set, `$question_number` will always be reset to 1. Also, please format the question, it's very difficult to follow.

Comment: I'm so embarrassed. Thanks so much, everyone for your comments,  @Ynhockey was right. test_session_id was causing the issues. I'll also separate the views from the controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ynhockey was right. test_session_id was causing the issues